# How can I use a function in Symfony?

Tags: function, symfony, controller, namespaces, repository

In my PagesRepository.php I created a function

```
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;


  function generateUid()
  {
     return Uuid::uuid4();
  }
```

Now I want to use this function in my PagesController.php:

```
$unique_id = generateUid();
```

But I get the error message:

> Attempted to call function "generateUid" from namespace
>   "App\Controller".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use the class name for static method call:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\PagesRepository;

class PagesController
{
    // ...

    $unique_id = PagesRepository::generateUid();

    // ...
}
```